# Variables that can contain string and/or number

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a variable that can contain string and/or number but in some case i have to remove numeric characters. So i am basicly;

```
if defined ARG2 (
    for %%b in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do set ARG2=!ARG2:%%b=!
)
```

It works almost all cases but there is a problem. If ARG2 contain nothing but numeric characters its changing ARG2 value to something like  `9=` . How can i fix this issue or is there a better way to remove numeric characters from variable?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. What input are you giving to get `ARG2` to expand to `9=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inputting `888` your for loop will reach 8 and remove all characters from the string. Therefore you have an empty variable. So when you try to remove 9 it expands to nothing, then for some reason (not entirely sure why) cmd doesn't consider the string manipulation, and just displays it (similarly `666` will output `7=` and so on). To fix this you simply need to add a check, to see if `ARG2` is empty or not.

```
if defined ARG2 (
    for %%b in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do if "!ARG2!"=="" ( goto :break ) else set ARG2=!ARG2:%%b=!
)
:break
```

This will just goto the `:break` label if `ARG2` expands to nothing.

The answers here - [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts) - should give some better explanation of why.